# Pdf reader with a function

Tags: php, pdf

I have a pdfreader.php and 4 other php files the pdfreader.php is in another directory than the 4 other php files.

I want to use functions in the pdfreader.php which lets people read the pdf file but all other pdf files have other functions which includes other files. Since i can only do 1 file in that $file variable. If there's another solution that would be appreciated aswell.

my code in pdfreader.php:

```
function test(){

$file = '../files/testtt.pdf';
$filename = 'testtt.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);

}
```

And in my other php files I have :

```
include '../includes/pdfreader.php';
test();
```

But when I try to load it says: Failed to load PDF document.

When I do it without functions it works.
I used it with this code first(without function):

```
echo "<a href='../includes/pdfreader.php' class='btndwn blue'> Check </a>";
```

If it's possible i want to do it with a button aswell.
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the 2 files are in different directories. When the other file calls **test()**, PHP resolves the path relative to the caller. You can try:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/../files/testtt.pdf';
```

Comment: They are in different directories that's true. But this solution didn't work. Still same error.

Comment: I updated the answer. `__DIR__` returns the absolute path to the file, and I had forgotten a slash.

Comment: Yes this worked! Do you know how I can put this into a button? Like i did before? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Creating a link, whose href attribute points to the new file, instead of pdfreader.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is wrong. How do you structure the folder? My guess is the folder `files` is in the folder `includes`. So the path in pdfreader.php should be `../includes/files/testtt.pdf`. When you run the other file, the current path is based on the other file. So when pdfreader.php included, the path in it is all wrong. It will search for files folder in the parent directory of current folder.

Comment: The solution above helped me. Thanks for your input though!!